# Prove that f’(x0) =g’(x0)

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Let f and g be *differentiable* functions on an interval $(a,b)$ such that $a < b$.
If there is $x0 ∈ (a,b)$ for which $f(x0) =g(x0)$ and $f(x) ≤ g(x)$ for all $x ∈ (a,b)$, **prove that** **$f’(x0) =g’(x0)$** 

I applied the MVT on f and g and I got:
$∃x0 ∈ (a,b)$ : $f’(x0) = [f(a)-f(b)]/[a-b]$
$∃x0 ∈ (a,b)$ : $g’(x0) = [g(a)-g(b)]/[a-b]$
Thus:
$f’(x0)/g’(x0)$ = $[f(a)-f(b)]/[g(a)-g(b)]$=...
If I can prove that that’s equal to $f(x0)/g(x0) = 1$ Then I’m done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** The function $h:=g-f$ has a minimum at $x_0$, what does it say about its derivative there?

Comment: h(x0)=0 but how does that relates to a minimum?

Comment: @Zachary Can $h$ take negative values?

Comment: you're right, h is always negative

Comment: I mean positive

Comment: So $ ∀x∈(a,b): h(x)≥0$ and $h(x0)=0$

Comment: @Zachary Indeed.

Comment: but how does that relate to my question though?

Comment: is the direction I'm going for going to work?

Comment: @Zachary I can't see how to solve the problem using your method.